# Can a label be placed separately from the form element it controls?

Tags: html, css, dom, checkbox, forms

CSS Tricks documents something called, ['the checkbox hack,'](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) in which elements are styled according to whether a checkbox is checked or not. This functionality is played with by styling the `<label>` element in order to make it appear as a link or a button, toggling the style of document elements when it is clicked.

In the [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1506530) provided, the checkbox is placed immediately following the label which describes it, and this is the configuration I normally see labels in—either immediately preceding, immediately following, or encapsulating the form element it controls.

However, in my specific use case scenario, I need the state of the checkbox to style multiple elements across multiple DOM nodes. As CSS has no parent selector, and the state of the checkbox is germane to the style of all the elements it controls, I believe it necessary to use relative CSS selectors such as `~` or `+` to style the elements. This necessitates placing the checkbox outside of the DOM node containing its label:

```css
/* Checkbox Hack */

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Default State */

div {
  background: green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Toggled State */

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div label {
  color: red;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<div>
  <label for="toggle-1">Toggle!</label>
</div>
<div>
  <div>A second element</div>
</div>
```

While this works (in Chrome, IE, Waterfox, and Vivaldi, at least), my question is about *validity*. Is it acceptable to place a `<label>` for a form element far away from that element itself, even outside the same DOM node? Are there any usability issues that might arise as a result of doing so?

Comment: As far as W3C I don't see issues other than the typical label1 goes with dom-element1 and so forth ...  As far as compliance I think you're ok .. It's just 'not normal'  ..  but neither is cutting paper with a knife, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it acceptable to place a `<label>` for a form element far away from that element itself, even outside the same DOM node?

Your HTML validates as valid HTML5 according to [this HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html), it appears to be valid as long as the `label` element's `for` attribute value is the ID of a [labelable element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-label) in the same document.

From [section 4.10.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) in [4.10 Forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html):

> The `for` attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of a [labelable element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-label) in the same Document as the `label` element. If the attribute is specified and there is an element in the Document whose ID is equal to the value of the `for` attribute, and the first such element is a [labelable element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-label), then that element is the `label` element's labeled control.

The `label` element in your example is explicitly associated with an `input` element in the same document, and the HTML validates, therefore it is acceptable. There is also an example provided in [this specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9) where the `label` element and the respective `input` element appear outside of the same DOM node.

In addition, it's also acceptable to associate more than one `label` element with the same `input` element if they are attached with the `for` attribute. From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9):

> More than one [`label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL) may be associated with the same control by creating multiple references via the [`for`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-for) attribute.

It's probably also worth mentioning that a `<label>` element can only contain [the following phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1), and it *cannot* contain descendant `<label>` elements.

---

> Are there any usability issues that might arise as a result of doing so?

I have seen issues on mobile devices where the `label` element doesn't check/activate the corresponding `input` element with touch events unless `user-select: none` is added to the `label` element.

Aside from that, I am not that I'm aware of any other issues.

Comment: Note that [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element) differs from W3C and considers that the label attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable element in the same tree whose root is the label element.

Answer (score 2):

> my question is about validity. Is it acceptable to place a `<label>`
>   for a form element far away from that element itself, even outside the
>   same DOM node?

Yes.

> Are there any usability issues that might arise as a result of doing
>   so?

No.

See [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

> **Permitted parent elements** Any element that accepts phrasing content.

---

> **for** 
>   The ID of a labelable form-related element in the same document as the label element. The first such element in the document
>   with an ID matching the value of the for attribute is the labeled
>   control for this label element.

Note also

> **form** `HTML5`
>  The form element that the label element is associated with (its form owner). If specified, the value of the attribute must
>   be the ID of a `<form>` element in the same document. This attribute
>   enables you to place label elements anywhere within a document, not
>   just as descendants of their form elements.